# What is the right macro for platform?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to write a pre-build event script that must be able to adapt the the build platform (Windows / Mac / Azure DevOps image) in my case.

So far I have found the **$(Platform)** macro but it returns me **AnyCPU**

What I need is **Darwin** or **Win32/Win64**, and I can't find it in the documentation.
Is there such a thing ?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT :

For Azure DevOps there is **Agent.OS** and **Agent.OSArchitecture**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It was as easy as moving from a build event to a MS Build [copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019).

Inside this task, you can have a condition on the OS.

For Windows:

```
<Target Name="CopyWindowsRTELogConfigFile" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
    <ItemGroup>
        <RTELogWindowsConfigurationJson Include="$(ProjectDir)Configuration\Windows_NT\$(ConfigurationName)\specific.rtelog.appsettings.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RTELogWindowsConfigurationJson)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

And Mac:

```
<Target Name="CopyDarwinRTELogConfigFile" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))'">
    <ItemGroup>
        <RTELogWindowsConfigurationJson Include="$(ProjectDir)Configuration\Darwin\$(ConfigurationName)\specific.rtelog.appsettings.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RTELogWindowsConfigurationJson)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```